# How to forcibly override find_package()

Tags: cmake

I want to build curl with a custom version of Brotli and I can't figure out how.

I tried to write a `FindBrotli.cmake` but curl ship it's own and override `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` so mine is never used. Currently I erase the curl's `FindBrotli.cmake` file but that is not an acceptable workaround and sometimes I want to not overload `FindBrotli.cmake`.

Answer (score 0):

CMake have [multiple modes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-modes) for finding dependencies with [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html). The default *module* mode look for `Find*.cmake` files in some places, the *config* mode look for [`*Config.cmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#package-configuration-file) files that by far I seen are basically the module variant with some automation so arguments handling is useless. In my case I made a directory and created `BrotliConfig.cmake` inside with this content :

```
if (NOT BROTLI_FOUND) # Necessary because the file may be invoked multiple times
    message(NOTICE "Using injected BrotliConfig.cmake")
    set(BROTLI_INCLUDE_DIRS "...")
    set(BROTLI_LIBRARIES "...")
    # Not done in my case but you can use this to create a target
    add_library(BROTLI::BROTLI UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(BROTLI::BROTLI PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${BROTLI_INCLUDE_DIRS}" IMPORTED_LOCATION "...")
endif()
```

Then to tell CMake to use my config, I set on the command-line:

- [`-DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_PREFER_CONFIG=1`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_PREFER_CONFIG.html) to make CMake perform lookups in *config* mode first
- [`-DBrotli_ROOT=/path/to/dir`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PackageName_ROOT.html) to tell CMake where to find our `BrotliConfig.cmake`
- [`-DCMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH=1`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH.html) to make CMake use the `Brotli_ROOT` setting above (already on by default)

This way I override the CMake module in curl without touching curl CMake code. I think that all `-DPackageName_ROOT=/path/to/...` can be replaced by a single CMake option but I'm not a CMake expert and the current solution satisfy me.

Comment: You can probably scope the effect of `CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_PREFER_CONFIG` to be narrower by defining it with `set()` just before the `find_package(curl)` and then `unset()` afterward.